# How To Display Only Owner Name?

Tags: elgg

I Wa't to display only Owner Name..in My Widget..
but i don't know how to do that.

[Image That Shows Owner Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoztK.png)

Answer (score 1):

Elgg framework has a MVC architecture where View knows Model/entities.

To solve this, View needs to get the owner entity which has to display in your widget, so: in *elgg/mod/(your widget folder)/views/default/widgets/(your name widget)/**content.php***, you should write the code of below:

```
<?php
$widget = elgg_extract('entity', $vars);
echo $widget->getOwnerEntity()->username;
```

Hope it helps!